# How to create fixed images?

Tags: android, image, android-layout

I drew my graphics for my application.
I have a sort of styled corner. The problem is that I don't know how to adapt it to all layouts.

Do I have to create more image for more layouts or is there something that let me to adapt?

Thanks for answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the style that you want in the styles.xml file and then reference that in each xml page you want it displayed. The link below has it better described, hope that helps

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html

Comment: So have I to draw different images?

Comment: you can use the same image over again, just declare it in your style.xml file and then reference that using '@style/image1' in the xml files that you want to use the image

Comment: But the same image could be lose quality?

Comment: You can edit the resolution in a picture viewer like preview on Mac, it'll take a little playing around with to get it right and the way you want

Comment: Did this fix you problem? please mark it the answer if it did to help other